# Ng-repeat with dynamic ng-model on input not working

Tags: angularjs

In controller I've a list like this:

```
scope.data = [ { user: { address: { city: 'Boston'} } } ];
```

And a property, where I've the name to access the object:

```
scope.propertyName = 'user.address.city';
```

In HTML, I've a ng-repeat where I put a dynamic input to edit that value.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <input ng-model="item[propertyName]">
</div>
```

My question is: How can I bind the value of the item with the ng-model?

Comment: Which value you need to bind ?

Comment: I need to change the value of the list with the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a directive with compile, to set ng-model indirectly:

```
compile: function(el, attrs) {
      return function(scope, el) {
        el.attr('ng-model', attrs.ngModelItem + '.' + scope[attrs.ngModelRef]);
        $compile(el)(scope);
      };
    }
```

please look my sample on jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/xizucu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Using this way working well, but the directive stay in loop.

Comment: I felt this appears very slow. I see another code when the original attribute for the directive had been removed to stop the loop. Something like el.removeAttr('ng-model-item') before the $compile line

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this because of `ng-repeat`:

```
<input ng-model="item.user.address.city" />
```

So you *do not* need to declare this:

```
$scope.propertyName = 'address.city';
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ze3pdbt/2/)

Comment: Yes, I need it. I don't know what value is this. He comes from database.

Comment: @DudisRoyer I don't understand - you have the value available with `item.user.address.city`?

Comment: So, I need to edit the value of this list with the input. But, i don't know the structure of the object, he comes from database.

Comment: I need to bind the value with the input, but the structure (user.address.city) have to be dynamic from a variable.

Comment: @DudisRoyer How will/could the structure differ from this? `{ user: { address: { city: 'Boston'} } }`

Comment: I'm making a generic datatable where is passed the data with the rows and a another property with the structure of each column.

Comment: @DudisRoyer ? If you can provide an example of how the structure for `address.city` could differ, I could help more.

Comment: I need to implement a solution that resolves all the possible structures. I don't have a standard to follow. I receive a list `[ { user: { address: { city: 'Boston'} } } ]` and the structure to the value `user.address.city`.

Comment: I can receive any list with any object, and I've to resolve.

Comment: @DudisRoyer 'All possible structures' - really? That could be anything! IMO 2 or 3 different structures is acceptable, but *any* structure could be a big mess. It sounds like your api/db needs  a consistent structure/standard. Anyway, this is outside the scope of the original question that is solved.

Comment: It's not a mess, it's a generic datatable. In the api that I'm working right now, have a consistent structure, but my solution have to work in any structure, for future projects. So, I've to use a variable to do this.

Comment: I solved this using focus, blur and click events. In controller I do the $parse and I'm set manually, but this is not a good solution to me.