# Compile Dynamic Directive

Tags: angularjs

Assume i've directive 'test' which has an isolated scope as `scope:{data:=}`
and i've another directive has link function as the following

```
link : function (scope,ele,att){
var testData = {bla:123};
var a = $compile(<test data = testData></test>)(scope)

}
```

so the question is how to pass testData Object to test Directive

Comment: What will be the destination of the var "a"?

Comment: @Joazito , i'll add a in dom

Comment: Can you create a plunker or jsbin with your code?

Comment: unfortunately i can't

Comment: Then, take a look in a working code with $compile, with I made before... Look my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183720/ng-repeat-with-dynamic-ng-model-on-input-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiled element takes the scope you pass in so add to the parent scope the data you need inside the child directive:

```
scope.data = toFoo
element.append($compile("<foo data='data' />")(scope))
```

Take a look at the example

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('bar',
    function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var toFoo = {
            s: 'ome',
            d: 'ata'
          }
          scope.data = toFoo
          element.append($compile("<foo data='data' />")(scope));
        }
      };
    }
  )
  .directive('foo',
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          data: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        template: "<div class='in'></div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.append(JSON.stringify(scope.data))
        }
      };
    }
  );
```

```css
.out {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.in {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="out" bar></div>
</div>
```